# Using std::thread with std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, join, concurrency, detach

I am trying mutex lock with independent threads. The requirement is, I have many threads which will run independently and access/update a common recourse. To ensure that the recourse is updated via a single task, I used mutex. However this is not working.

I have pasted code, a representation of what I am trying to do below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>


std::mutex mt;
static int iMem = 0;
int maxITr = 1000;


void renum()
{
    // Ensure that only 1 task will update the variable
    mt.lock();
    int tmpMem = iMem;
    usleep(100); // Make the system sleep/induce delay
    iMem = tmpMem + 1;    
    mt.unlock();
    printf("iMem = %d\n", iMem);
}

int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxITr; i++) {
        std::thread mth(renum);
        mth.detach(); // Run each task in an independent thread
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this is terminating with the below error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I want to know if the usage of <thread>.detach() is correct above? If I use .join() it works, but I want each thread to run independently and not wait for the thread to finish.
I also want to know what is the best way to achieve the above logic.

Comment: When you return from `main()` the process will exit, so any work still unfinished in the threads will not complete. Waiting for them using `join()` is a perfect thing for `main()` to do before it returns.

Comment: A *thousand* threads seems quite-the-overkill. Try and get this up with something manageable; (like 3). And you're not waiting on your threads, so as soon as you're done throwing up threads `main()` terminates, finishing your process; probably *not* what you want. For this I would suggest a thread-detach is wrong. Rather you should foist them into a `std::vector<>`, then join them *all* before `main()` terminates.

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks for the comment. So if I use .join(), will each thread run independently or wait for the previous thread to complete? My requirement is that each thread should run independently. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Warning, you're reading `iMem` outside the lock with your printf.

Comment: [OT]: You may use `std::lock_guard` (or `std::unique_lock`) instead of locking/unlocking yourself. Or maybe use `std::atomic`.

Comment: @Jarod42 , I tried lock_guard and unique_lock, but it didn't work. Can you share an example (using my above example), it will be helpful.

Comment: `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mt);` (Don't forget to name it, else the `unlock` is done immediately) [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3273c2a95e37dabe).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> mths;
  mths.reserve(maxITr);
  for (int i = 0; i < maxITr; i++) {
    mths.emplace_back(renum);
  }
  for (auto& mth : mths) {
    mth.join();
  }
}
```

This way, you retain control of the threads (by not calling `detach()`), and you can join them all at the end, so you know they have completed their tasks.

Comment: Thanks. I need 1 clarification. will thread.join() make every taks run independently or will all the remaining task have to wait for the main task to finish (.join())?

Comment: The threads will be allowed to run and complete independently, with the exception of the main thread which will wait for all of them (specifically, it will wait for `mths[0]` to finish, then for `mths[1]` to finish, etc., but of course the threads could have finished in any order.

Comment: are you saying that mths[1] will run only after mths[0] finishes, irrespective of accessing shared object? Or both will run in parallel, but when it comes to accessing shared resource (iMem) mths[1] will wait for mths[0] to release the lock from iMem object?

Comment: The threads will run concurrently; the only serialized part is that you `join()` them in order.  This is all fine.  There is no guarantee about which thread will execute "first."