# C++11 and async, how does it work?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I am a bit confused as to how `async` works/should work. When I call a task in `async`, I was under the impression, all these tasks will run in parallel. An example code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void asyncSleep()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}

int main()
{
    int noOfASyncTask = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfASyncTask; i++) {
        async(std::launch::async, asyncSleep);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

The method `asyncSleep()`, sleeps for 1sec. So when I run this with `noOfASyncTask` task as 10, the execution took nearly 10sec. When I increase the `noOfASyncTask` to 20, it took around 20sec. So this means the async tasks do no run in parallel. Why does this behave this way? And how do I make the tasks run in parallel?

PS: The `noOfASyncTask` could be any number (dynamic).

Answer (score 7):

The destruction of return value of your `async` call, which happens at the end of the full-expression (i.e. the semicolon), blocks until the call of the asynchronous function has returned.

Move the returned future to an object that's destroyed later if you don't want that.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> laters;

    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
    {
        laters.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, asyncSleep));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run with noOfASyncTask  = 10 and your logic (using vector) it's run in milliseconds (although the time for sleep is 1 sec). But when I run with noOfASyncTask  = 20, this runs out of memory. Any idea why? I tried it online: http://ideone.com/t4oHQ5

Comment: @Kerrek N.B. not "deferred function call" ... that means something very different in the context of `std::async` (and would not block if it was deferred)

Comment: @programmer, your ideone test didn't link with `-pthread` so it doesn't start any threads, it throws an exception and exists immediately.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Yes, good point -- what would you call the thing that's bound to `async`?

Comment: How can you "detach" a future from the task that it runs, if you don't want to wait for the result and don't want to store the futures?

Comment: @ᐅJohannesSchaub-litbᐊ: That would be a pretty awkward thing in general. The future may not have any associated execution context, and such "detaching" may result in complete discarding of the work. You could do `std::thread([f = std::move(my_future)]{f.wait();}).detach();` to be safe.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I wouldnt use thread..detach as it runs into other issues (Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458753/using-stdthread-with-stdmutex).

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I am trying to compile it in windows (using GCC 5.1). What would be the option/alternate to -pthread here? (IDE: CodeBlock).

Comment: @KerrekSB, I tend to say "the asynchronous function" or "the async function", which is also potentially ambiguous ;)